# Bool tool and shading

Tags: modifiers

After booling with difference there is left weird shading on cube. How to fix it?

[image]

http://www.mediafire.com/file/hutki3noraf0ksg/bt.blend

Comment: It's because there are some ngons created by Bool Tools. Add more loop cuts to the mesh and use autosmooth. Or just model it by hand, it will be very simple (keep only quads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Ways you can fix it

Click the Cube and go to shading in the left hand tool panel instead of smooth just click **Flat**
[image]

OR

Click on the cube and apply the boolean modifier only and add the edge split modifier to it. And bring the edge split modifier on the top then the bevel modifier in the order.
[image]

Comment: In both ways bevel is gone.

Comment: on click of flat shading how the bevel is removed its applied the flat shading nothing else and the bevel is at the outer side not inside of the cube

Comment: Yeah, bevel without smooth shading.

Comment: and notice there is no bevel inside u have to add bevel

Comment: In OP example there are both inside and outside bevels. Still those methods are bad habits because of 'dirty' mesh topology.